# Storing binary data within core data on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-data

If I record an audio file and I have a core data object representing that recording... should I be referencing just the url to the recording on disk, or could I just store it within core data?

It's probably easier to just store it within core data, but doesn't sound like a very good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would store the path to the file.  This would be better because you can pass around the path until you actually need to play the file.

Answer (score 1):

Writing down entities in Core Data is atomic if I remember. So if you are going to save down the data I'd go with a path. If the application is only going to be reading relatively small to medium blobs you would be fine with a one-to-one related entity I think.

Also with the limited memory in the iPhone keeping data as files will let you [mmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258091/when-should-i-use-mmap-for-file-access) them.