# Reading big files sequentially

Tags: c++, c, linux, io

How to process (in read-only fashion) a big binary file in `C/C++` on `Linux` as fast as possible? Via `read` or `mmap`? What buffer size? (No boost or anything.)

Comment: Sequentially or random access?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mmap is faster and optimal for read only applications.  See answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/258097/1094175

Comment: That answer is mostly accurate, but the bit about, "mmap allows all those processes to share the same physical memory pages, saving a lot of memory" is bunk -- the filesystem cache does this.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [madvise](http://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise) with [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise), and you might also call [readahead](http://linux.die.net/man/2/readahead) (perhaps in a separate thread, since it is a blocking syscall).

If you read the file using ordinary [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), consider using [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) and pass buffers of 32kbytes to 1Mbytes to [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)...

Call `mmap` on big enough regions; at least several dozen of megabytes (assuming you have more than 1Gb of RAM), and if you have a lot of available RAM, on bigger regions (up to perhaps 80% of available RAM).

Take care of resource limits e.g. set with [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit)

For not too big files (and not too much of them), you could `mmap` them entirely. You'll need to call e.g. [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) to get their size. As a rule of thumb, when reading one (not several) big files on my desktop machine I would `mmap` it in full it if is less than 3Gb.

If performance is important, take time to benchmark your application and your system, and to tune it accordingly. Getting the parameters (like mmap-ing region size) configurable makes sense.

The `/proc/` filesystem, notably inside `/proc/self/` from your application, gives several measures (e.g. `/proc/self/status`, `/proc/self/maps`, `/proc/self/smaps`, `/proc/self/statm` etc.)

GNU libc should use `mmap` for reading `FILE`s which you have [`fopen`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fopen.3.html)-ed with `"rm"` mode.