# What happens when a numpy memmap array is copied?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am read-onlying from a 70GB memmap array, but only using ~300MB from it. Learning from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12384169/2558506) answer, memmap doesn't actually use physical memory, so I figured I should copy the required array into physical memory for better performance.

However,  when I np.copy() a memmap and np.info() the copied array, the class is a memmap. Regardless of this speculation, I see more memory usage and improvement in performance when using a copied array.

Does a copied memmap use physical memory? Or is something else going on behind the scene? Is it that it just looks like I'm using physical memory for the copied array, and my computer is deceiving me like always?

Comment: I think that mmap and your memmap is different things

Comment: Yes, they are different, but `numpy.memmap` uses `mmap`, so the question is still relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`numpy.memmap` is a subclass of `numpy.ndarray`. `memmap` does not override the `ndarray.copy()` method, so the semantics of `ndarray.copy()` are not touched. A copy into newly-allocated memory is indeed made. For a number of reasons, `ndarray.copy()` tries to keep the type of the returned object the same when a subclass is used. It makes less sense for `numpy.memmap` but much more sense for other subclasses like `numpy.matrix`.

In the case of `numpy.memmap`, the `mmap`-specific attributes in the copy are set to `None`, so the copied array will behave just like a `numpy.ndarray` except that its type will still be `numpy.memmap`. Check the `._mmap` attribute in both the source and the copy to verify.

Comment: +1 for the answer with proof! `._mmap` of an actual memmap gives me `<mmap.mmap object at 0x7f32c64ce768>`, but `._mmap` of a copied array gives me `None`.

Comment: Apparently `np.copy` *does not* preserve subclass, while `ndarray.copy` does.  Since the OP specified `np.copy`, doesn't this explain why memory consumption went up?