# How would I design and implement a non-blocking memory mapping module for node.js

Tags: node.js, mmap, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

There exists the mmap module for node.js: https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-mmap/

As the author Ben Noordhuis notes, accesing mapped memory can block, which is why he does not recommend it anymore and discontinued it.

So I wonder how would I design a non-blocking memory mapping module for node.js? Threading, Fibers, ?

Obviously this nearby raises the question if threading in node.js would just happen elsewhere instead of the request handler.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When talking about implementing some native facility in a non-blocking fashion, the first place to look is [libuv](http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/introduction.html).  It is how node's core modules interface with the underlying platform.  Of particular interest is the [work queue](http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/threads.html#libuv-work-queue) API.

If we take a quick look at [node-mmap's source](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-mmap/blob/0.0.4/mmap.cc#L33-45), we see that it's actually extremely simple.  It calls `mmap` and returns a node `Buffer` that wraps the mapped memory region.

Reading from this `Buffer` is what results in the OS performing I/O.  Because that will necessarily happen on the JS thread, we end up blocking the JS thread with disk I/O.

Instead of returning a `Buffer` that allows JS direct access to the mapped memory, you should write a wrapper class in C++ that marshals reads and writes through the work queue.  In this way, the disk I/O will happen on a separate thread.

In JS, you'd use it something like this:

```
fs.open('/path/to/file', 'r', function(err, fd) {
    fs.fstat(fd, function(err, stats) {
        var mapped = mmap.map(stats.size, mmap.PROT_READ, mmap.MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
        mapped.read(start, len, function(err, data) {
            // ...
        });
    });
});
```

And in C, the `read` function would create a libuv work request and queue it in the work queue.  The C worker function would then read the mapped memory range (based on the caller's specifications), which may cause disk I/O, but this is safe because it is happening on a separate thread.

What happens next is interesting.  The safe approach would be for the worker to `alloc` a new chunk of memory and `memcpy` from the mapped memory.  The worker then passes a pointer to the copy, and the C callback wraps it up in a `Buffer` to be returned to JS-land.

You could also try reading over the range (so that any necessary I/O happens on the worker thread) but not actually doing anything with the data, and then having the C callback simply wrap the mapped memory range in a `Buffer`.  In theory, the parts of the file that the worker read would stay in RAM, so access to that portion of mapped memory would not block.  However, I honestly don't know enough about mapped memory to say whether this might end up biting you.

---

Finally, I'm dubious about whether this will actually provide any extra performance over node's regular `fs` methods.  I would only go down this road if I was doing [something that really justifies using `mmap`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/258091/201952).