# What is the functionality of munmap, mmap

Tags: c++, c, linux, system-calls

When I try to study some piece of code that deals with FPGA, I came across with munmap, mmap.

I go through the manual provided [here](https://linux.die.net/man/2/munmap). I am still not understanding the purpose of this function. What exactly this does?

Comment: I recommend reading the great answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258091/when-should-i-use-mmap-for-file-access.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mmap()` is a system call, which helps in memory-mapped I/O operations. It allocates a memory region and maps that *into* the calling process virtual address space so as to enable the application to access the memory.

`mmap()` returns a pointer to the mapped area which can be used to access the memory.

Similarly, `munmap()` removes the mapping so no further access to the allocated memory remains legal.

These are lower level calls, behaviourally similar to what is offered by memory allocator functions like `malloc()` / `free()` on a higher level. However, this system call allow one to have fine grained control over the allocated region behaviour, like,

- memory protection of the mapping (read, write, execute permission)
- (*approximate*) location of the mapping (see `MAP_FIXED` flag)
- the initial content of the mapped area (see `MAP_UNINITIALIZED` flag)

etc.

You can also refer to the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) if you think alternate wordings can help you.

Answer (score 3):

It maps a chunk of disk cache into process space so that the mapped file can be manipulated at a byte level instead of requiring the application to go through the VFS with `read()`, `write()`, et alia.

Comment: unless it's `MAP_ANONYMOUS`, in which case there is no file :)

Answer (score 2):

The manual is clear:

> mmap() creates a new mapping in the virtual address space of the calling process

In short, it maps a chunk of file/device memory/whatever into the process' space, so that it can directly access the content by just accessing the memory.

For example:

```
fd = open("xxx", O_RDONLY);
mem = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

Will map the file's content to `mem`, reading `mem` is just like reading the content of the file `xxx`.

If the `fd` is some FPGA's device memory, then the `mem` becomes the content of the FPGA's content.

It is very convenient to use and efficient in some cases.