# mmap File-backed mapping vs Anonymous mapping in Linux

Tags: linux, process, ipc, mmap

- what is the main difference between File-backed mapping & Anonymous
  mapping.
- How can we choose between File-backed mapping or Anonymous
  mapping, when we need an IPC between processes.
- What is the    advantage,disadvantage of using these.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*mmap()* system call allows you to go for either file-backed mapping or anonymous mapping.

> void *mmap(void *addr, size_t lengthint " prot ", int " flags ,int fd,
>   off_t offset)

**File-backed mapping**- In linux , there exists a file */dev/zero* which is an infinite source of 0 bytes. You just open this file, and pass its descriptor to the ***mmap()*** call with appropriate flag, i.e., `MAP_SHARED` if you want the memory to be shared by other process or `MAP_PRIVATE` if you don't want sharing.

Ex-

```
     .
     .
if ((fd = open("/dev/zero", O_RDWR)) < 0)
printf("open error");
if ((area = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,fd, 0)) == MAP_FAILED)
  {
      printf("Error in memory mapping");
      exit(1);
  }
close(fd); //close the file because memory is mapped
  //create child process 
    .
    .
```

Quoting the man-page of mmap() :-

> The contents of a file mapping (as opposed to an anonymous mapping;
>   see MAP_ANONYMOUS below), are initialized using length bytes starting
>   at offset offset in the file (or other object) referred to by the file
>   descriptor fd. offset must be a multiple of the page size as returned
>   by sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE).

In our case, it has been initialized with zeroes(0s).

Quoting the text from the book **Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment by W. Richard Stevens, Stephen A. Rago II Edition**

> The advantage of using /dev/zero in the manner that we've shown is
>   that an actual file need not exist before we call mmap to create the
>   mapped region. Mapping /dev/zero automatically creates a mapped region
>   of the specified size. The disadvantage of this technique is that it
>   works only between related processes. With related processes, however,
>   it is probably simpler and more efficient to use threads (Chapters 11
>   and 12). Note that regardless of which technique is used, we still
>   need to synchronize access to the shared data

After the call to `mmap()` succeeds, we create a child process which will be able to see the writes to the mapped region(as we specified `MAP_SHARED` flag).

**Anonymous mapping** - The similar thing that we did above can be done using anonymous mapping.For anonymous mapping, we specify the `MAP_ANON` flag to mmap and specify the file descriptor as -1.
The resulting region is anonymous (since it's not associated with a pathname through a file descriptor) and creates a memory region that can be shared with descendant processes.
The advantage is that we don't need any file for mapping the memory, the overhead of opening and closing file is also avoided.

```
if ((area = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0)) == MAP_FAILED)
   printf("Error in anonymous memory mapping");
```

So, these file-backed mapping and anonymous mapping necessarily work only with related processes.

If you need this between unrelated processes, then you probably need to create named shared memory by using  `shm_open()` and then you can pass the returned file descriptor to `mmap()`.

Comment: you said "these file-backed mapping and anonymous mapping necessarily work only with related processes." why do we need file-mapped mmap. How does it help when compared to anonymous mapping.

Comment: When you go for file-backed mapping, the Virtual address space of the process gets mapped to the file. So, when you access that memory, you will be reading the file which has been mapped to that region. Whereas, anonymous mapping maps an area of the process's virtual memory not backed by any file. The contents are initialized to zero.In this respect an anonymous mapping is similar to malloc, and is used in some malloc(3) implementations for certain allocations.

Comment: when you `mmap()` using /dev/zero, it's the same as if you do with anonymous mapping.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap explains the two very well.Read the section on Memory visibility to get detailed info. It's short and precise.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that in file-backed mapping, the Virtual address space of the process gets mapped to the file. But how is it helpful. why can't we just use anonymous. why do we need file-backed mapping?

Comment: Probably the following thread should be able to answer your query -

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258091/when-should-i-use-mmap-for-file-access