# Java, why reading from MappedByteBuffer is slower than reading from BufferedReader

Tags: java, io, mappedbytebuffer

I tried to read lines from a file which maybe large.

To make a better performance, I tried to use mapped file. But when I compare the performance, I find that the mapped file way is even a a little slower than I read from `BufferedReader`

```
public long chunkMappedFile(String filePath, int trunkSize) throws IOException {
    long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
    logger.info("Processing imei file, mapped file [{}], trunk size = {} ", filePath, trunkSize);

    //Create file object
    File file = new File(filePath);

    //Get file channel in readonly mode
    FileChannel fileChannel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r").getChannel();

    long positionStart = 0;
    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
    long lineCnt = 0;
    while(positionStart < fileChannel.size()) {
        long mapSize = positionStart + trunkSize < fileChannel.size() ? trunkSize : fileChannel.size()  - positionStart ;
        MappedByteBuffer buffer = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, positionStart, mapSize);//mapped read
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++) {
            char c = (char) buffer.get();
            //System.out.print(c); //Print the content of file
            if ('\n' != c) {
                line.append(c);
            } else {// line ends
                processor.processLine(line.toString());
                if (++lineCnt % 100000 ==0) {
                    try {
                        logger.info("mappedfile processed {} lines already, sleep 1ms", lineCnt);
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }
                line = new StringBuilder();
            }
        }
        closeDirectBuffer(buffer);
        positionStart = positionStart + buffer.limit();
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    logger.info("chunkMappedFile {} , trunkSize: {},  cost : {}  " ,filePath, trunkSize, end - begin);

    return lineCnt;
}

public long normalFileRead(String filePath) throws IOException {
    long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
    logger.info("Processing imei file, Normal read file [{}] ", filePath);
    long lineCnt = 0;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            processor.processLine(line.toString());
            if (++lineCnt % 100000 ==0) {
                try {
                    logger.info("file processed {} lines already, sleep 1ms", lineCnt);
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }            }
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    logger.info("normalFileRead {} ,   cost : {}  " ,filePath, end - begin);

    return lineCnt;
}
```

Test result in Linux with reading a file which size is 537MB:

MappedBuffer way:

```
2017-09-28 14:33:19.277 [main] INFO  com.oppo.push.ts.dispatcher.imei2device.ImeiTransformerOfflineImpl - process imei file ends:/push/file/imei2device-local/20170928/imei2device-13 , lines :12758858 , cost :14804 , lines per seconds: 861852.0670089165
```

BufferedReader way:

```
2017-09-28 14:27:03.374 [main] INFO  com.oppo.push.ts.dispatcher.imei2device.ImeiTransformerOfflineImpl - process imei file ends:/push/file/imei2device-local/20170928/imei2device-13 , lines :12758858 , cost :13001 , lines per seconds: 981375.1249903854
```

Comment: I'd be more suspicious about the code with `mmap` that you wrote. The `BufferedReader` way is straightforward and hard to get wrong (if you have basic experience). Mapping a file and processing it like you're doing looks really ineffective. If you profile the app, you might find the hotspot is in your approach of going through every byte and casting it to a `char`.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect that what I am doing is not a good way, any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

That is the thing: file IO isn't straight forward and easy.

You have to keep in mind that your **operating system** has a *huge* impact on what exactly is going to happen. In that sense: there are no solid rules that would work for all JVM implementations on all platforms.

When you really have to worry about the last bit of performance, doing in-depth profiling on your *target* platform is the primary solution.

Beyond that, you are getting that "performance" aspect wrong. Meaning: memory mapped IO doesn't magically increase the performance of reading a single file within an application once. Its major advantages go along this path:

> mmap is great if you have multiple processes accessing data in a read only fashion from the same file, which is common in the kind of server systems I write. mmap allows all those processes to share the same physical memory pages, saving a lot of memory.

( quoted from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/258097/1531124) on using the C `mmap()` system call )

In other words: you example is about reading a file contents. In the end, the OS still has to turn to the drive to read all bytes from there. Meaning: it reads disc content and puts it in memory. When you do that the *first* time ... it really doesn't matter that you do some "special" things on top of that. To the contrary - as you do "special" things the memory-mapped approach might even be slower - because of the **overhead** compared to an "ordinary" read.

And coming back to my first record: even when you would have 5 process reading the same file, the memory-mapped approach isn't necessarily faster. As the Linux might figure: I already read that file into memory, and it didn't change - so even without explicit "memory mapping" the Linux kernel might cache information.

Comment: But Linux should support maped file well, is there anything I am doing wrong with reading from mapped buffer?

Comment: Of course it supports it!  The point is that memory mapped file I/O is not necessarily faster.  Irrespective of how you do it.

Comment: @StephenC Good feedback. Did help me to further enhance my answer, to the point I simply forgot to mention ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The memory mapping doesn't really give any advantage, since even though you're bulk loading a file into memory, you're still processing it one byte at a time. You might see a performance increase if you processed the buffer in suitably sized `byte[]` chunks. Even then the `BufferedReader` version may perform better or at least almost the same.

The nature of your task is to process a file sequentially. `BufferedReader` already does this very well and the code is simple, so if I had to choose I'd go with the simplest option.

Also note that your buffer code doesn't work except for single byte encodings. As soon as you get multiple bytes per character, it will fail magnificently.

Answer (score 2):

GhostCat is correct.  And in addition to your OS choice, other things that can affect performance.

- Mapping a file will place greater demand on physical memory.  If physical memory is "tight" that could cause paging activity, and a performance hit.
- The OS could use a different read-ahead strategy if you read a file using `read` syscalls versus mapping it into memory.  Read-ahead (into the buffer cache) can make file reading a lot faster.
- The default buffer size for `BufferedReader` and the OS memory page size are likely to be different.  This may result in the size of disk read requests being different.  (Larger reads *often* result in greater throughput I/O.  At least to a certain point.)

There could also be "artefacts" caused by the way that you benchmark.  For example:

- The first time you read a file, a copy of some or all of the file will land in the buffer cache (in memory)
- The second time you read the same file, parts of it may still be in memory, and the apparent `read` time will be shorter.

Comment: Didnt notice your answer ... but well, equal minds, equal thinking ;-)