# How portable is mmap?

Tags: windows, linux, macos, mmap

I've been considering using `mmap` for file reading, and was wondering how portable that is.
I'm developing on a Linux platform, but would like my program to work on Mac OS X and Windows.

Can I assume `mmap` is working on these platforms?

Comment: While my answer does not address the portability aspect of mmap, Boost offers alternatives in Boost.Interprocess and Boost.Iostreams which seems to work on Linux as Windows.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`mmap()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) function is a POSIX call.  It works fine on MacOS X (and Linux, and HP-UX, and AIX, and Solaris).

The problem area will be Windows.  I'm not sure whether there is an `_mmap()` call in the POSIX 'compatibility' sub-system.  It is likely to be there — but will have the name with the leading underscore because Microsoft has an alternative view on namespaces and considers `mmap()` to intrude on the user name space, even if you ask for POSIX functionality.  You can find a definition of an alternative Windows interface [`MapViewOfFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366761%28VS.85%29.aspx) and discussion about performance in another SO question ([`mmap()` vs reading blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972/mmap-vs-reading-blocks)).

If you try to map large files on a 32-bit system, you may find there isn't enough contiguous space to allocate the whole file in memory, so the memory mapping will fail.  Do not assume it will work; decide what your fallback strategy is if it fails.

Answer (score 4):

The principle of a memory mapped file is fairly portable, but you don't have mmap() on Windows (but things like MapViewOfFile() exist). You could take a peek at the python mmap modules c code to see how they do it for various platforms.

Answer (score 3):

Using mmap for reading files isn't portable if you rely on mapping large bits of large files into your address space - 32-bit systems can easily not have a single large usable space - say 1G - of address space available so mmap would fail quite often for a 1G mapping.

Answer (score 1):

I consider memory mapped io on UNIXs
as not useable for interactive applications, 
as it may result in a SIGSEGV/SIGBUS 
(in case of the file has been truncated meanwhile by some other process).
Ignoring such sick "solutions" as setjmp/longjmp
there is nothing one can do other than to terminate the process after getting SIGSEGV/SIGBUS.
The new G++ feature to convert such signals into exceptions
seems to be intended mainly for apples OS,
since the description states, that one needs runtime support for this G++ feature
and there is no information to be found about this G++ feature anywhere.
We probably have to wait a couple of years, until structured exception handling like it can be found on windows since more than 20 years makes its way into UNIXs.

Comment: Although you didn't directly answer the question I found this really helpful, thank you.

Comment: memory mapped io not being useable for non trivial applications on UNIXs affects portability of memory mapped io

Comment: Why would you make the other process truncate your file if you know the app would crash? (As a protection against user incompetence there's the fairly standard fcntl()-based locking mechanism.)