# C++ io streams versus mmap

Tags: c++, io, iostream, mmap

I am starting a small project for a key-value store, in C++. I am wondering how C++ std streams compare to mmap in terms of scalability and performance. How does using ifstream::seekg on a file that wouldn't fit in RAM compare to using mmap/lseek?

Comment: Why don't you make a small test and see? Anyways, there're a lot of variables like portability, distribution, actual problem to solve and so on.

Comment: What kind of data? What size? What computer?

Comment: This is basically covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588605/mmap-vs-read although iostreams introduce additional overhead to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, any Linux user-land application is using [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), including the C++ I/O library.

With *great care*, `mmap` and `madvise` (or `lseek` + `read` & `posix_fadvise`) could be more efficient that C++ streams (which are using `read` and other [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...); but a misuse of syscalls (e.g. `read`-ing too small buffer) can give catastrophic performance

Also, Linux has a very good [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) (used to contain parts of recently accessed file data). And performance also depends upon the [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) (and the hardware -SSD and mechanical hard disks are different beasts- and computer).

Maybe you should not reinvent your own thing and use [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/), or [gdbm](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdbm/), or [redis](http://redis.io), or [mongodb](http://mongodb.org), or [postgresql](http://postgresql.org/), or [memcached](http://www.memcached.org/), etc...

Performance and trade-offs depend strongly on the actual use (a single 4Gbytes log file on your laptop is not the same as petabytes of video or genomics data in a datacenter). So benchmark (and notice that many tools like the ones I mentioned can be tuned wisely).