# Does FreeBSD support memory mapped files?

Tags: c++, stl, freebsd, memory-mapped-files

I am using a FreeBSD OS, I want to write into a file which is on the disk, but, it will take a lot of time, so, I was suggested to use Memory mapped file. But, I am in a dilemma whether FreeBSD supports it or no???.. Please, somebody can guide me??.. I am programming in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, FreeBSD has [memory mapped files](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mmap&apropos=0&sektion=2&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html). No, the STL does not include any special support for them. Consider using [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html).

Answer (score 6):

Any UNIX (Posix compliant OS) has [`mmap`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/mmap.html), so yes FreeBSD has it.

STL does not exist as such. (see e.g. [What's the difference between "STL" and "C++ Standard Library"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-this-stl-vs-c-standard-library-fight-all-about))

You mean:

> Does the C++ standard library 'have' it?

No, the C++ standard library does not directly provide/wrap support for mmap. However, you can have a look here:

- [mmap() vs. reading blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972/mmap-vs-reading-blocks)
- Boost::Iostreams already has a mapped_file: [`boost::iostreams::mapped_file`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html)