# How to compare all the lines in a sorted file (file size > 1GB) in a very efficient manner

Tags: performance, file

Lets say the input file is:

```
Hi my name NONE
Hi my name is ABC
Hi my name is ABC
Hi my name is DEF
Hi my name is DEF
Hi my name is XYZ
```

I have to create the following output:

```
Hi my name NONE 1
Hi my name is ABC 2
Hi my name is DEF 2
Hi my name is XYZ 1
```

The number of words in a single line can vary from 2 to 10. File size will be more than 1GB.

How can I get the required output in the minimum possible time. My current implementation uses a C++ program to read a line from the file and then compare it with next line. The running time of this implementation will always be O(n) where n is the number of characters in the file.

To improve the running time, the next option is to use the mmap. But before implementing it, I just wanted to confirm is there a faster way to do it? Using any other language/scripting?

Comment: `number of words in a single file can vary from 2 to 10. File size will be more than 1GB`... So we're dealing with words with an average length of greater than 100 million letters?

Comment: I think the OP meant to say 2 to 10 words *per line*.

Comment: 1. Is the file sorted?  I presume so from the method you describe. 2. Is this homework? If so you should tag it as such.  If not, any reason you can't use `uniq`?

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes. I have made following changes a) no of words in a single line, 2 to 10 and b) corrected the i/p data

Comment: No, this is not a homework. This is a performance problem I am facing in the Project. The regular C++ program is taking just too long to generate the required o/p. The i/p file is one of the o/ps from the previous processing step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uniq -c filename | perl -lane 'print "@F[1..$#F] $F[0]"'
```

The perl step is only to take the output of `uniq` (which looks like "2 Hi my name is ABC") and re-order it into "Hi my name is ABC 2". You can use a different language for it, or else leave it off entirely.

As for your question about runtime, big-O seems misplaced here; surely there isn't any chance of scanning the whole file in *less* than O(n). `mmap` and `strchr` seem like possibilities for constant-factor speedups, but a stdio-based approach is probably good enough unless your stdio sucks.

The [code for BSD uniq](http://opensource.apple.com/source/text_cmds/text_cmds-31/uniq/uniq.c) could be illustrative here. It does a very simple job with `fgets`, `strcmp`, and a very few variables.

Comment: Ok. I just fired the uniq command. let me see how it performs. Thanks for ur advice.

Comment: Dear hobbs, it worked blazingly fast. For a file of 665MB, it just took 35s. Whats the magic?

Comment: @PiyushKansal There is no secret. uniq just reads the file line-by-line using `fgets` and compares the line to the previous line using `strcmp`. If they're the same, it increments a counter. If they're different, it prints the previous line together with the count. It uses pointer swaps to exchange the "current line" and "previous line" to avoid copying the strings.

Comment: I got it now, so the key is pointer swap !! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases this operation will be completely I/O bound. (Especially using well-designed C++)

Given that, its likely the only bottleneck you need to care about is the disk.

I think you will find this to be relevant:
[mmap() vs. reading blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972/mmap-vs-reading-blocks)

Ben Collins has a very good answer comparing mmap to standard read/write.

Comment: Actually, on some systems it can hit pretty badly on the memory management and thus Garbage Collection...

Answer (score 0):

Well there is two time scales you are comparing which aren't related to each other really. The first is algorithmic complexity which you are expressing in O notation. This has, however, nothing to do with the complexity of reading from a file.

Say in the ideal case you have all your data in memory and you have to find the duplicates with an algorithm - depending on how your data is organized (e.g. a simple list, a hash map etc) you can find duplicates you could go with O(n^2), O(n) or even O(1) if you have a perfect hash (just for detecting the item).

Reading from a file or mapping to memory has no relation to the "big-Oh" notation at all so you don't consider that for complexity calculations at all. You will just pick the one that takes less measured time - nothing more.