# Why is MD5Sum so fast

Tags: c++, performance, md5, md5sum

I've been studying hashing in C/C++ and tried to replicate the md5sum command in Linux. After analysing the source code, it seems that md5sum relies on the md5 library's md5_stream. I've approximated the md5_stream function from the md5.h library into the code below, and it runs in ~13-14 seconds. I've tried to call the md5_stream function directly and got ~13-14 seconds. The md5sum runs in 4 seconds. What have the GNU people done to get the speed out of the code?

The md5.h/md5.c code is available in the CoreUtils source code.

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include "md5.h"

#define BLOCKSIZE 32784

int main()
{
    FILE *fpinput, *fpoutput;

    if ((fpinput = fopen("/dev/sdb", "rb")) == 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("input file doesn't exist");
    }

    struct md5_ctx ctx;
    size_t sum;

    char *buffer = (char*)malloc (BLOCKSIZE + 72);
    unsigned char *resblock = (unsigned char*)malloc (16);
    if (!buffer)
      return 1;

    md5_init_ctx (&ctx);
    size_t n;
    sum = 0;

    while (!ferror(fpinput) && !feof(fpinput)) {
        n = fread (buffer + sum, 1, BLOCKSIZE - sum, fpinput);
        if (n == 0){
            break;
        }
        sum += n;

        if (sum == BLOCKSIZE) {
            md5_process_block (buffer, BLOCKSIZE, &ctx);
            sum = 0;
        }
    }

    if (n == 0 && ferror (fpinput)) {
        free (buffer);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Process any remaining bytes.  */
    if (sum > 0){
      md5_process_bytes (buffer, sum, &ctx);
    }

    /* Construct result in desired memory.  */
    md5_finish_ctx (&ctx, resblock);
    free (buffer);

    for (int x = 0; x < 16; ++x){
        std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex << static_cast<uint16_t>(resblock[x]);
        std::cout << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    free(resblock);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Was a default mkspec problem in Fedora 19 64-bit.

Comment: When you build your code, are you building in debug mode?  What optimization levels are you using?

Comment: It's gnuutils... the source is available and you can look at it yourself.

Comment: Tim : Currently I'm building in Qt. By default the Qt build environment adds the -O2 build flag. I compile and test in Release mode, so debugging libraries and hooks should not be interfering.

MarcB : I obviously know that it's GNUUtils if I'm looking at the md5sum source code. I am looking for insight in how or where they optimized their build.

Comment: you already have the sources, look at the makefile to figure what compiler options are used.

Comment: Do you believe that the optimizations are all compile flags?

Comment: Yes, the Makefile(s) should contain all the compilation flags.  Do a `make clean` followed by `make` and see what flags were passed to the compiler.

Comment: Fedora x64 with the default Qt install uses the wrong mkspec file and doesn't use the optimization flags it should. linux g++ (-O) vs linux-64 g++(-O2/-O3). I deleted the generic linux mkspec and made a symbolic link to the proper linux-64 mkspec. All is well and it optimized properly.

Comment: You should write that solution as an answer, and then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an error in the Qt mkspecs regarding an optimization flag not being set properly.

Answer (score 3):

fread() is convenient, but don't use fread() if you care about performance.  fread() will copy from the OS to a libc buffer, then to your buffer.  This extra copying cost CPU cycles and cache.

For better performance use [open()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) then [read()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) to avoid the extra copy.  Make sure your read() calls are multiples of the block size, but lower than your CPU cache size.

For best performance use [mmap()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap)  map the disk directly to RAM.

If you try something like the below code, it should go faster.

```
//  compile  gcc  mmap_md5.c  -lgcrypt
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <gcrypt.h>
#include <linux/fs.h> // ioctl

#define handle_error(msg) \
do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        char *addr;
        int fd;
        struct stat sb;
        off_t offset, pa_offset;
        size_t length;
        ssize_t s;
        unsigned char digest[16];
        char digest_ascii[32+1] = {0,};
        int digest_length = gcry_md_get_algo_dlen (GCRY_MD_MD5);
        int i;

        if (argc < 3 || argc > 4) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s file offset [length]\n", argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
        if (fd == -1)
            handle_error("open");
        if (fstat(fd, &sb) == -1)           /* To obtain file size */
            handle_error("fstat");
        offset = atoi(argv[2]);
        pa_offset = offset & ~(sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) - 1);


        if (sb.st_mode | S_IFBLK ) {
            // block device. use ioctl to find length
            ioctl(fd, BLKGETSIZE64, &length);

        } else  {
            /* offset for mmap() must be page aligned */
            if (offset >= sb.st_size) {
                fprintf(stderr, "offset is past end of file size=%zd, offset=%d\n", sb.st_size, (int) offset);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if (argc == 4) {
                length = atoi(argv[3]);
                if (offset + length > sb.st_size)
                    length = sb.st_size - offset;
                /* Canaqt display bytes past end of file */
            } else {    /* No length arg ==> display to end of file */
                length = sb.st_size - offset;
            }
        }
        printf("length= %zd\n", length);
        addr = mmap(NULL, length + offset - pa_offset, PROT_READ,
                                MAP_PRIVATE, fd, pa_offset);
        if (addr == MAP_FAILED)
            handle_error("mmap");


        gcry_md_hash_buffer(GCRY_MD_MD5, digest, addr + offset - pa_offset, length);

        for (i=0; i < digest_length; i++) {
            sprintf(digest_ascii+(i*2), "%02x", digest[i]);
        }
        printf("hash=%s\n", digest_ascii);

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: have you actually measured the performance gain? On what type of file system? For sequential file access, I am wondering how mmap could perform significantly better than buffered reads. I would also have expected sequential fread to perform better than unbuffered read on the vast majority of file systems.

Comment: The original poster was checking a block device /dev/sdb   so the file system type is irrelevant.   File systems sit above block devices.  I tested performance of mine vs md5sum and performance is about the same,  my example is about 5% slower than md5sum but not over three times slower compared to original poster.   If you want more debate on mmap. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972/mmap-vs-reading-blocks

Comment: Sadly, it was a compilation problem in this case. Thank you for the code and insight. I will definitely check out the linked articles.