# Read data faster from files

Tags: c++, c, pcap, libpcap, winpcap

I have question about seek in files.

I have pcap file and I need to seek for a specific packet.  so far, this is my code for finding that packet:

```
while (!find_the_packet) 
 {
   pcap_next_ex(p_pcap, &header, &data); //read the next packet
   check_if_the_packet_found();
 }
```

and it is working great.

my goal is finding that packet faster- not checking packet by packet until I find it.

so I built data base- Hash Map with (key,value). lets say that the

```
key   -> No. of the packet
value -> the packet itself (or the location of the packet)
```

I also noticed the pcapnav library function:
 `pcapnav_goto_offset(pcapnav_t *pn, off_t offset, pcapnav_cmp_t boundary)`

and I saw that this function uses FSEEK. so my data base is not very helpful because the FSEEK works serially (correct me if I wrong).

so my question-

is the FSEEK really works serially? read chunk by chunk? how does it works? I am bit confused..

if so, is there faster way to get specific packet\chunk of data from pcap file?

thanks in advanced.

Comment: Yes you're wrong about [`fseek`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek), all it does is set the position where the next read/write should happen, basically it's just a variable assignment.

Comment: Although it may depend on the underlying file system, fseek (and the following read) is understood to work in nearly constant time on modern implementations.

Comment: Hi, thanks! this is my confusion- suppose the position is set to specific point inside the file, lets say 300MB from the current position. is the cursor will get to the next read\write position immediately?

Comment: In my very simplified understanding a sequential read of 512 bytes requires 1 disk operation and fseek to 300MB offset plus read of 512 bytes requires around 6 disk operations. Of course, the actual time is also influenced by the actual state of I/O caching.

Answer (score 2):

Fseek only tells the underlying library ([libc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libc)) where the next read should happen. Libc will then forward the request to the operating system (typically using the [lseek](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) system call). So, in order to read at a given position you have two system calls (lseek, read) and one copy (which the read does from the filesystem buffers (aka [cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache)) to the address space of your program).

If the file you're going to read is smaller than the size of the available RAM and will be mostly [cached](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) then you'll [benefit from mmap-ing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972/mmap-vs-reading-blocks). In that case you can also ask the operating system to lazily prefetch the file (using [madvise](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) or [PrefetchVirtualMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/Hh780543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). If the file is larger than the available RAM and/or accessed sporadically then the read speed will be limited by the disk I/O, making the difference between seek+read and mmap insubstantional.

Comment: thank you for your helpful answer! let me see if I understand you- if the available RAM is 512B and I want to seek to 5GB, is the operating system will "take" 5GB\512B chunks (chunk by chunk), do nothing with them, and only then- when it gets to the (5GB\512B) chunk perform read?

Comment: and my only chance to make it faster is to load the content of the file to the program's memory, arrange it to MAP (key,value) and when I wat to perform seek, I will do that vary fast (MAP time)?

Comment: @user3378689 No, the filesystem won't scan the file sequentially, it has a map telling it where exactly on the disk is 5gb (cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode_pointer_structure). And no, you can't improve the speed by loading the file into the RAM if the file is larger than the available RAM.