# how to decrement a FILE* pointer in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to decrement a FILE pointer in C , but I don't get it done, here is my code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main() {
    FILE* inputFile = NULL;
    double* inputData = NULL; 
    unsigned int windowSize = 512; 
    unsigned int index1 = 0, index2 = 0, i = 0;
    double temp = 0.0;

    // mememory allocation
    inputData = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*windowSize);

    // Opning files 
    inputFile = fopen(" file","rb");

    if (inputFile == NULL) {
        printf("Couldn't open either the input or the output file \n");
        return -1;
    }
    while((i=fread(inputData,sizeof(double),windowSize,inputFile))==windowSize){   
        for (index1 =0; index1 < windowSize;index1++) {
            printf("index %d \t %d    %d\t %lf\n",index1,index2,i,inputData[index1]);
            fprintf(outputFile,"%lf ",inputData[index1]);
        }
        index2++;
    }
    // I need to start read from the end of the file - the value of i
    printf( " the last i %d \n", i);
    inputFile-i;
    while (!(feof(inputFile))) {  // the program doesnt'T get into the loop
        fread(&temp,sizeof(double),1,inputFile);
        printf("\n\n %lf \n",temp);
    }
    fclose(inputFile);
}
```

any idea idea how may I do this?

**UPDATE**

I ve changed the code based on doc of `fseek` like :

```
i=i*-1;

printf( " the last i %d \n", i);

fseek(inputFile ,i*sizeof(double),SEEK_END);
while(( fread(&temp,sizeof(double),1,inputFile)==1 )) {
    printf(" %lf \n",temp);
}
```

the program doesn't crash but it shows a one wrong value of temp

```
0.000000
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: you don't "decrement" or "increment" filehandles. It's literally just an int used to lookup stuff in an internal-only array somewhere. If you want to move where that filehandle is pointing at in a file, then use `fseek()`

Comment: Also `inputFile-i;` doesn't do anything.

Comment: well to be honest , I didn't know I can do this, it was a disparate try to do this, how  can I use fseek to jump to the end-X , if I don'T know how long is the file, and how x may be

Comment: See [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Comment: And have a look at the `fseek` documentation.

Comment: @mafso I'ce update my question !

Comment: What is your input? Is it only printing one value before stopping? Or does the output include a value you weren't expecting? Or is it printing a value that isn't in the input? You should do more work to clarify your revised question to help others help you.

Comment: if you want to "increment/decrement" there is memmap

Comment: `mmap` still requires knowing the file size (which can be obtained from an `fstat()` call) to specify the bounds from the end of the file. The `fseek()` call allows seeking from the file's end more directly. Additionally, `mmap` will usually be slower than `fseek`, if the program makes only one pass through the file.

Comment: @AlexReynolds - I'd love to see any data supporting your argument that fseek is faster than mmap.  My experience and every benchmark I have seen says otherwise except where the OS uses a mapping underneath the covers for *`read`/*`write` (windows does, but the only portable way is to use mmap directly * http://stackoverflow.com/a/46005/1162141 )

Comment: Test it yourself--you'll see that a single pass is faster with C I/O calls, while multiple passes are faster with `mmap`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`fseek()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fseek.html) to move the file offset to the desired byte, before using `fread()`.

You can seek from the start of the file, the end, or from wherever the file offset is currently. The documentation I linked to explains how.

Comment: 1. Thanks 2.is there a way to use fseek to jump to the position END -X  ? if I don't know the how big the file is, which mean that I don't know how X will be ?

Comment: @Engine: RTFM!!! You've even got the link. Shall we copy-and-paste that text here?

Comment: @Engine: The third argument to `fseek()` can be `SEEK_SET`, `SEEK_CUR`, or `SEEK_END`.  Guess which one you need?  The second argument is a signed quantity, so it can be positive or negative (though a negative offset from the start won't get you anywhere).