# Will mmap be more efficient than read, if the buffer size is much larger than the page size?

Tags: c++, io, posix, mmap

The page size is 4096 bytes. Assume that you want a buffer twice as much, that is 8192 bytes.

If you use `mmap` you will map 8192 bytes without doing anything else (reading the actual data from the disk).

Then when you access the first byte, a page fault will occur and you will do one I/O to read the first page from the disk. After reading this page, you will get the first byte as an answer.

Then when you access the 4097-th byte, a new page fault will occur and you will do an extra I/O to read the second page from the disk to get this byte.

However, if you use `read`, you will only have to do one I/O to read 8192 bytes and then return the two bytes that you want.

This is a very small example, but I am kind of thinking what about if the buffer size is a few KB or MB? It looks like mmap with a page of size 4096 bytes will generate a lot of I/Os that can be avoided if you just the POSIX `read` call instead, which makes me wonder, why use `mmap` in the first place?

Comment: some platforms might page in several pages in the background, not causing as many page faults (and if you intend to re-process data, i.e. "read" it more than once, the situation is naturally different). There's no real answer to this question without writing a benchmark for your problem, on your platform.

Comment: There are several questions on this site along this subject matter, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972/mmap-vs-reading-blocks/6383253#6383253

Comment: Your assumptions are adventurous. In practice, the OS will start reading ahead before you touch the first page, and it will normally not read fewer than 32 pages at a time (of course there is no guarantee, but that's what happens in practice). Comparing performance for 8kB of data is somewhat silly, too. `mmap` has its merits, but optimizing a 8kB load is not one of them. Think about `mmap` when you're loading at least a megabyte.