# Comparing speed of fread vs. read.table for reading the first 1M rows out of 100M

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a 14GB data.txt file. I was comparing the speed of `fread` and `read.table` by reading the first 1M rows. It looks like `fread` is much slower although it is not supposed to be. It takes some time until the percentage counts show up.

What could be the reason? I thought it was supposed to be super fast... I am using a Windows OS computer.

Comment: Define "much slower" - if it's measured in microseconds then I wouldn't be losing sleep. Also, without example code noone can verify what you're doing.

Comment: @thelatemail: I have a data table 100M rows, 60 columns. This is 14 GB. When I read   first 1M rows, it takes 1.5-2 mins (there is a wait time until the percentage count shows) whereas read.table takes less than a minute. Irrespective of this comparison, I have been hearing from others that `fread` is reading their 4GB table in 40 sec. There is something wrong that I can't figure out.

Comment: This is the code I use: `data=read.table('data.txt',sep=',',nrow=1000000,header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data=fread('data.txt',sep=',',nrow=1000000)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`fread` `mmap`s the file. This takes some time, and will map the whole file. This means subsequent "read-ins" will be faster.

`read.table` does not `mmap` the whole file. It can read in the file line by line [and stop at line 1000000].

You can see some background on `mmap` at [`mmap()` vs. reading blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972/mmap-vs-reading-blocks)

The examples in the help from `fread`  highlight this behaiviour

Comment: So if I will read the file only once, can we say that using `fread` won't give much of an advantage?

Comment: @KTY, if you are only trying to read in the first million lines, and only once, then you may have found a case where fread won't give and advantage. If you want to read the whole file, or read the rest of the lines in subsequently, then `fread` should almost definitely be faster.

Comment: yes, it seems like the main difference comes when reading big files...now reading the whole 14GB  file, it is very fast compared to `read.table`. Thanks for the information on `mmap`.

Comment: @KTY We could speed up reading the first N rows.  Just wasn't a priority as normally you want to read the whole file. I filed a feature request [#1300](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1300).