# How does the kernel-side page cache virt <-> phys mapping interact with the TLB?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86-64, mmap, tlb

I am writing an application that makes heavy use of `mmap`, including from distinct processes (not concurrently, but serially). A big determinant of performance is how the TLB is managed user and kernel side for such mappings.

I understand reasonably well the user-visible aspects of the [Linux page cache](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Page_Cache_Basics). I *think* this understanding extends to the userland performance impacts<sup>1</sup>.

What I don't understand is how those same pages are mapped into kernel space, and how this interacts with the TLB (on x86-64). You can find lots of information on how this worked in the 32-bit x86 world<sup>2</sup>, but I didn't dig up the answer for 64-bit.

So the two questions are (both interrelated and probably answered in one shot):

1. How is the page cache mapped<sup>3</sup> in kernel space on x86-64?
2. If you [`read()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) N pages from a file in some process, then again read exactly those N pages again from another process on the same CPU, it possible that all the kernel side reads (during the kernel -> userpace copy of the contents) hit in the TLB? Note that this is (probably) a direct consequence of (1).

My overall goal here is to understand at a deep level the performance difference of one-off accessing of cached files via `mmap` or non-`mmap` calls such as `read`.

---

<sup>1</sup> For example, if you `mmap` a file into your processes' virtual address space, you have effectively asked for your process page tables to contain a mapping from the returned/requested virual address range to a physical range corresponding to the pages for that file in the page cache (even if they don't exist in the page cache, yet). If `MAP_POPULATE` is specified, all the page table entries will actually be populated before the `mmap` call returns, and if not they will be populated as you fault-in the associated pages (sometimes with optimizations such as [fault-around](https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/2/28/531)).

<sup>2</sup> Basically, (for 3:1 mappings anyway) Linux uses a single 1 GB page to map approximately the first 1 GB of physical RAM directly (and places it at the top 1 GB of virtual memory), which is the end of story for machines with <= 1 GB RAM (the page cache necessarily goes in that 1GB mapping and hence a single 1 GB TLB entry covers everything). With more than 1GB RAM, the page cache is preferentially allocated from "HIGHMEM" - the region above 1GB which isn't covered by the kernel's 1GB mapping, so various [temporary mapping](https://linux-mm.org/HighMemory) strategies are used.

<sup>3</sup> By *mapped* I mean how are the page tables set up for its access, aka how does the virtual <-> physical mapping work.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww - thanks for the note, but it's a programming and development question - not only is the answer itself about programming (how is the kernel programmed), it is actually directly related to programming I'm doing targeting the `mmap` function. I already read the help guide and it is explicit on-topic here: `software tools commonly used by programmers`. Furthermore, there are a ton of great similar questions with great answers here (yes I get that just because other off topic questions exist doesn't mean you can ask more, but this isn't off topic, so don't worrk).

Comment: Finally, if reasonable minds could disagree (and they can here) - just leave it be. I don't know if you've asked these types of development-oriented questions on SU or Unix SE, but you don't get good answers. Those communities are largely for expert users of such systems, not developers. ... and _dev ops_? I think you misunderstood the thrust of my question.

Comment: @jww - I modified the question a bit to make it clear it's a question that arises about the use of `mmap` in an application I'm developing.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm optimizing an application that wants to sequential-read a ~100MB file of big-endian float32 into its own large buffer before further processing.  I'm trying to figure out whether it's better to mmap and copy+vpshufb on the fly, or whether to `read()` in 128k or 64k chunks and then modify in-place for that block that's still hot in L2.  I don't have perf counters on the Haswell-EP VM this runs on, so it's annoying to experiment.  Since mmap of files can't use hugepages, `read()` might beat `mmap(MAP_POPULATE)` if the kernel is memcpying from 1G or 2M pages.

Comment: @PeterCordes - well I think I know how it works on x86-64 at least: the kernel maps the entire physical memory into its virtual address space 1:1, at `__START_KERNEL_map`, so when the kernel wants to access user-mode memory it has to do the translation manually (e.g., by walking the page table), giving it a physical address, and then it simple adds `__START_KERNEL_map` to get a virtual address in that 1:1 mapping. It seems to use 1G pages to the extent possible for that mapping, see for e.g., [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/mm/init.c?v=4.4#L313).

Comment: So the short answer seems to be that if you aren't using 1G pages yourself, at least the active 16 GB kernel linear mapping is only using up those TLB entries. I guess that's neither here nor there wrt my actual question though because it isn't clear to me what pool the _page cache_ pages are taken from. Of course in userland, page cache entries are mapped in as 4K, but on the kernel side are they just using the big linear mapping? I think (and hope) yes, since that would be a pointless drain on the TLB otherwise (and I don't see any limitation to doing it that way).

Comment: On `mmap` specifically, I ended up just testing it. The one-off linear read should be the best possible case for `read()` and `write()` but I still found `mmap()` faster, but only by say 10%-40%. When reading large files (say 100MB+), I could get around 10 GB/s from `mmap()` versus a `memcpy` bandwidth of ~13 GB/s, so it is pretty close to the max already. For files that fit in L3, the gap was much larger. I put a lot of details on the tradeoffs I found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41419353/149138). @PeterCordes

Comment: Although `read/write` don't have access to xmm/ymm to do fast memcpy, they get around it nicely by using `movsb` or `movsd` when those are fast, so they reach high speeds, with some startup overhead. Probably a problem with `read/write` is that they never really get rolling because they do everything a page at a time, so they need to keep starting up the copy, paying overhead and hurting next page prefetch. The main overhead in `mmap` is setting up the user page table and the cost is about the same with and without MAP_POPULATE due to fault-around. @PeterCordes

Comment: Finally, if you are on a quite recent kernel (4.8 or 4.9) some file systems such as `tmpfs` will support 2 MB pages in their page cache. That should be a _big_ win for both `mmap` and `read/write` since the page-handling overhead is reduced by a factor of 512. I haven't tested it since I'm on an older kernel. Even on old kernels you can test it in a hacky way by creating a file on hugetlbfs, but files go away when the creating process does, so you create a file, keep the process around and run your tests :p

Answer (score 1):

Due to vast virtual address space compared to physical ram installed (128TB for the kernel), the common trick is to permanently map all the ram. This is known as "direct map".

In principle it is possible that both relevant TLB and cache entries survive the context switch and all the other code executed, but it is hard to say how likely this can be in the real world.

Comment: So the entire RAM is direct mapped in the kernel, probably using large pages (e.g., 1 GB pages if available)? Granted TLB entries may be flushed arbitrarily due to capacity conflicts, but I'm taking the optimistic view - i.e., is it _possible_ that the TLB entries can survive, or does the kernel (for example) flush them on syscall exit?

Comment: I already said it can survive. Also, flushing TLB (even if only the kernel range) on switch back to usermode would be very expensive and wasteful - there are no issues with letting entries linger.

Comment: How is the page cache accessed in the kernel then? Does the page cache just store the phys address for each 4k block and then there is a fixed offset added to get the (kernel view) virt address? Or is it something more complex?

Comment: It is roughly what you state here. I can only suggest you inspect the implementation.